# How can we stop spring cloud task in spring cloud data flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am trying to stop a running task in spring cloud data flow , but the spring batch application didn't get terminated and in spring cloud data flow server task status it is still running.
Is there any way we can stop the task and can get status as expected as failed.